# Python Accurate Sampling

Tags: python, monitoring, timing, sampling

I am trying to sample cpu registers every millisecond and calculate the frequency. To have an accurate measurement, I require that the sampling time to be very accurate. I have been using the time.sleep() to achieve this but sleep is not very accurate past 1 second.

What I would like to do is set up a counter and sample when that counter reaches a certain value and where the counter is incremented at an accurate rate. I am running Python 2.6. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there are likely several Python packages out there that -help- with what you want. I also suspect Python is not the right tool for that surpose.

There is the timeit module

There is time module with clock() which is NOT a wall clock but a CPU usage clock (for the application initializing the time.clock() object. It is a floating point value which shows some 12+ digits below the ones place ie 1.12345678912345. Python floats are not know for there accuracy and the return value from time.clock() is not something I personally trust as accurate.

There are other Python introspection tools that you can google for, like inspect, itertools, and others, that time processes. however I suspect their accuracy is dependant on running averages of many iterations of measuring the same thing.